# vb.net dropdownlist populate

Tags: .net, datetime, drop-down-menu

i need to populate my dropdownlist with month and year values to getdate + 1 year. I also want them in text format so "January 2009 and not 1 2009.
This is the code i have written to populate the values. how do i convert them to January from 1?

Public Sub Load_xxxx(ByRef DDL As System.Web.UI.WebControls.DropDownList)
        Try
            Dim i As Integer
            Dim j As Integer
            For i = Now.Year To Now.Year
                For j = Now.Month To Now.Month + 11
                    DDL.Items.Add((j.ToString) + " " + (i.ToString))
                Next
            Next
        Catch ex As Exception
            ReportError(ex)
        End Try
    End Sub

Answer (score 0):

If your just trying to convert the integer value to month name an easy way to do it
would be just to create an array of strings containing the month names and use your j value
as the index.

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
Dim time As DateTime = DateTime.Now
    Dim j As Integer
    For j = 0 To 11
        DDL.Items.Add((time.AddMonths(j)).ToString("MMMM"))
    Next
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim time As DateTime = DateTime.Now
DDL.Items.Clear()
While time <= time.AddYears(1)
    DDL.Items.Add((time.AddMonths(j)).ToString("MMMM yyyy"))
    time = time.AddMonths(1)
Next
```